# Пятно вместо текста three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Сделал рендеринг 3D текста по примеру из документации, но вместо текста получаю пятно.

```js
let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE);
camera.position.x = -50;
camera.position.y = 30;
camera.position.z = 40;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

let loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load('./helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', (font) => {
    let geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry('enemy', {
        font: font,
        size: 1,
        height: 5,
        curveSegments: 12,
        bevelEnabled: true,
        bevelThickness: 10,
        bevelSize: 8,
        bevelSegments: 5
    });
    let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xcccccc});
    let header = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(header);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В сцене не хватает источник(а, ов) света, так как используется `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()` - его видимость зависит от того, насколько интенсивно он освещается. Поскольку источников света нет, то объект с данным материалом - черный.

```js
let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.x = -50;
camera.position.y = 30;
camera.position.z = 40;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
light.position.setScalar(10);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

let loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', (font) => {
  let geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry('enemy', {
    font: font,
    size: 14,
    height: 5,
    curveSegments: 12,
    bevelEnabled: true,
    bevelThickness: 4,
    bevelSize: 4,
    bevelSegments: 2
  });
  let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xcccccc
  });
  let header = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(header);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

PS Заодно привел параметры геометрии текста к более вменяемым. Иначе было не понятно - что там за объект вообще :)

Comment: Спасибо, только начал знакомиться с three.js, все это пока для меня новое. Но суть понял, сцена, камера, геометрия, материал и вот еще источник света.